# Execute SQL query taken from Table with Laravel DB Raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a project build with Laravel 8. My project will use for creating dynamic report that run with SQL query. So i must save the SQL query in my database to run dynamic every report.

It's all fine since i faced problem if my query are dynamic.

my code on Controller:

```
public function data(){
   $id = 1092
   $var = DB::table('abc')->where('id', $id)->first();
   $query = $var->query;

   return $query
}
```

If i run that code, will result like this:

```
SELECT * FROM V_REPORT WHERE PRQ_DATE BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' AND COMPANY = '$company'
```

And i will run that query using `DB::raw` on other function.

```
public function runDb(Request $request){
  $start_date = $request->start_date; // ex: 2022-10-01
  $end_date = $request->end_date; // ex: 2022-10-05
  $company = $request-> company; // ex: A
  $query = $this->data();
  $sql = DB::select(DB::raw("$query"));

  return $sql;

}
```

*output: []*

I expect will get data from V_REPORT, but its null. whereas when I run in the database, there is a lot of data that appears.

I think the problem are because the "query" read as string. and the `DB::raw` function not read that "variable" on query `('$start_date', $end_date, '$company')`.

FYI, there are no error response from my code. It just return `[]`, which means there are no data.

Is there any way to run my "dynamic query" from table on `DB::raw()` ?

Please help, i am stuck on this thing.

Comment: Why don't you use Eloquent?

Comment: because my project need to save Raw SQL query on database. So I use query builder DB::raw() to handle it. But it face problem when i use dynamic variable on my query

Answer (score 0):

`DB::select($query)` will run your Raw Query. You dont need to use `DB::raw()` inside `DB::select()`

```
public function runDb(Request $request){
 $start_date = $request->start_date; // ex: 2022-10-01
 $end_date = $request->end_date; // ex: 2022-10-05
 $company = $request-> company; // ex: A
 $query = $this->data();
 $sql = DB::select($query);

 return $sql;

}
```

**See Documentation** :  https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/5-ways-to-use-raw-database-queries-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm in your runDb function what the response you are getting for following code

1. `$query = $this->data()`
2. `DB::raw("$query")`

```
public function runDb(Request $request){
  $start_date = $request->start_date; // ex: 2022-10-01
  $end_date = $request->end_date; // ex: 2022-10-05
  $company = $request-> company; // ex: A
  $query = $this->data();
  $sql = DB::select(DB::raw("$query"));

  return $sql;
}
```